# How come this simple flask app is not working on ec2?

Tags: python, flask, post, amazon-ec2

There is an app running on ec2 @ `ec2<ip>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com` which expects a post request, but upon executing the request - it seems to hang

The code for the server is here:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    payload = request.data
    event = json.loads(payload)
    print(payload, event)
    return "200"
```

And is running using:

```
python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

However, when I post to it using:

```
import requests

url = 'http://ec2<ip>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com/webhook'
myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

x = requests.post(url, json = myobj)

print(x.text)
```

It hangs...

It hangs - what is the issue?!

Comment: Did you check that you can reach that EC2 instance from the internet? For example you can run `python3 -m http.server 8080` to check it.

Comment: When I run this in the ec2 instance, it returns `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...` with a hang

Comment: Yes, but try to open the `http://ec2<ip>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com:8080` from your browser, and see if it responds. The "with a hang" is that is waiting for connections, the server is running.